# Adding images twice for ios retina app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, retina-display

Good day, 
My question is that do we have to add each and every image twice while developing for an ios retina application?

For example if there are two images in my app a.png and b.png both of 20x20px. So do I need to add four images :

```
    -a.png (20x2x)
    -a@2x.png(40x40)
    -b.png (20x20)
    -b@2x.png (40x40)
```

Is there anyway I can proceed with adding a single big image and make it resize on both screens?

Comment: if you just add either the _normal_ or the _retina_ images only, the iOS creates the missing images with the desired resolution for its own way. sometimes, that images can be definitely ugly, so the best way when you add all images to the application and you would not trust the iOS - but it will do it for you, if you are lazy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to add both images a.png and a@2x.png. The ios itself will look for @2x identifier and will use that image for retina resolution devices.If you will not add a.@2x.png then the image will look blur and distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to, if you don't add the retina images, images will look distorted

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add both sets of images. The system looks at the '@2x' identifier and appropriately displays them on retina devices if those images are available. Now way around that if are willing to compensate with distortions by using only the normal (non 2x) images.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a bigger image like a @2x, but named as normal. The main issue is that you will consume twice the needed memory (with a cost also for resizing) when you open this image on normal display. A solution could be create your own image view that starting from big images resize them correctly redrawing them. I use a similar approach for image that I download from the internet. Of course that have a cost in performance.
To sum up:

- -open the image memory increase (1)
- -redraw the image in a half size memory increase (1+0.5=1.5)
- -you don't need the old image anymore, just release it (1.5-1 = 0.5)
- -use it

  This approach requires more code, more resource from the device but you can just add one kind of image in the bundle
  Hope this helps.